# C# returning Dictionary references safely

Tags: c#, dictionary, immutable-collections

I'm considering three approaches for returning references to internal Dictionary instances (C#) in regards to code safety and impact on the code readability/visually for a project I'm working on.

I've narrowed it down to the following three approaches, but am open to better suggestions. Currently I prefer **#3** as the best balance of safety without extra boiler plate.

**1)** Use a second ReadOnlyDictionary instance to wrap internal Dictionary, only ever letting the ReadOnlyDictionary escape the class:

**2)** Return the Dictionary instance as an IReadOnlyDictionary, but recasting would allow it to be modified so not as safe as option #1 or #3.

**3)** Return Dictionary.ToImmutableDictionary() as a ImmutableDictionary when it escapes the containing class so that the returned object is an immutable view of the inner dictionary, although this will make a new copy for every call incurring a higher cost, that should be fine with small simple dictionaries (which mine are).

```
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> innerDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    // Only required for Example #1
    private readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> readonlyInnerDictionary;

    public ExampleClass() {
        // Only required for Example #1
        readonlyInnerDictionary = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>(innerDictionary);
    }   

    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> GetExampleOne() {
        // Requires a second dictionary which is more boiler plate but the object being returned is truly readonly
        return readonlyInnerDictionary;     
    }

    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> GetExampleTwo() {
        // Requires InnerDictionary be defined as Dictionary (Not IDictionary) but doesn't require the second dictionary be defined
        // which is less boiler plate, but the object returned could be re-cast to it's mutable form meaning it's not truly mutation safe.
        return innerDictionary;
    }

    public ImmutableDictionary<string, string> GetExampleThree() {
        // Truly immutable object returned, but a new instance is built for every call; fortunately all of my dictionaries are small (containing at most 9 keys)
        return innerDictionary.ToImmutableDictionary();
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Determined that the neatest, easiest and safest; but not the most performant solution is to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` internally which ensures thread safety (from `System.Collections.Concurrent`) and then to use the `System.Collections.Immutable` to call `dictionary.ToImmutableDictionary()` which creates the dictionary which escapes the inner class. The interface signature is for `ImmutableDictionary<KeyType, ValueType>`.

This is not the most performant solution, but in my case with dictionaries with less than 12 keys and small simple objects representing state in most cases that is not a concern.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 is the way to go. You can recast ReadOnlyDictionary to IDictionary, but that will throw an Exception when trying to mutate:

```
 void CastingTest()
        {
            var dic1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dic1.Add("Key", "Value");
            var dic2 = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>(dic1);
            var castedDic = (IDictionary<string, string>)dic2;
            castedDic.Add("AnotherKey", "Another Value"); //System.NotSupportedException, Collection is read only
        }
```

The ReadOnlyDictionary doesn't create another Dictionary. It points to the same reference of the first one, encapsulating it. So if you do:

```
void AddTest()
        {
            var dic1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dic1.Add("Key", "Value");
            var dic2 = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>(dic1);
            dic1.Add("Key2", "Value2"); //Now dic2 have 2 values too.
        }
```

Never expose your innerDictionary and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Syntax Did it solve your doubt? I can share more details if you want.

Comment: Sorry for the delay Arthur, your feedback was very helpful in furthering discussion, however I found another solution which I preferred more after discussing this further with friends; for anyone interested I have provided it as an answer to my own question and marked it as accepted.

Comment: No problem but, hmm, you never specified that you wanted thread safety and, even then, ReadOnlyDictionary is thread safe if you never expose the Dictionary that you're wrapping.

Comment: Some of the classes mutate the dictionary on multiple threads (workers) internally; I was using lock object()s to guard them but didn't mention that in the question, then I switched to ConcurrentDictionary instead.